# Get Last Value from Previous Window Partition in Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

[image]

Hi I am trying to get the value from previous quarter end (last column) as shown in the image.

For Attribute A, Month 4, Quarter 2 it should return value of Month 3 in the previous quarter (30). Same goes for Months 5 and 6.

All quarters with no previous quarters should return 1.
The same should apply across other attributes.
I have tried using LAG() and LAST_VALUE() functions with partitions without success as I am not able to get the last quarter end value.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The previous quarter has three values.  It is unclear which you want.  The largest?  The last?

Comment: I want the value from the last month's value from the previous quarter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there's no missing month, LAST_VALUE plus COALESCE is the way to go:

```
coalesce(last_value(case when month in (3,6,9,12) then value end ignore nulls)
         over (partition by attribute
               order by month
               rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
        , 1)
```

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth, this worked! I have a follow up question to this. In case I want to get the sum of values of the previous quarter, how would the logic go? 

Instead of getting 30 as the previous qtr end value in Line 4, would require 60. 
10 + 20 + 30 = 60 (Sum of previous quarter values)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You need a Derived Table with a nested SUM (PARTITION BY attribute, quarter) to get the quarterly sum and then apply above logic.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I was struggling with nesting an analytical function into another which would throw an error, however calculating the nested sum in a join and putting this in an analytical function worked! Many thanks dnoeth!

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I think the simplest method is to use `join`, fetching the one row per quarter that you want:

```
select t.*, coalesce(tt.value, 1) 
from t left join
     (select t.*
      from t
      qualify row_number() over (partition by quarter order by month desc) = 1
     ) tt
     on tt.quarter = t.quarter - 1;
```

Comment: Thank you both Gordon and Dnoeth for your answers. I have been facing others issues with building the dataset and will get back to you both after testing the results. Much appreciated!